# Object does not render

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object, meteor

How can I render the first name object onto the screen? I am having trouble with doing so. *I am not using the meteor provided accounts package(s).* Keep in mind that **the name of the template that the js code for shown is registration** and **the template named dashboard is the html shown below.**(If that makes any sense.)

```js
Template.registrationForm.events({
'click input[name=submitBtn]' : function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var userName = username.value;
    var passWord = password.value;
    var firstName = firstname.value;
    var lastName = lastname.value;
    var emailAddress = emailaddress.value;

    if (userName == "") {
        console.log("Null");
    }

    if (passWord == "") {
        console.log("Null");
    }

    if (firstName == "") {
        console.log("Null");
    }

    if (lastName == "") {
        console.log("Null");
    }

    if (emailAddress == "") {
        console.log("Null");
    }

    // insert user's info into the database.
    UsersList.insert({
            uname: userName,
            pword: passWord,
            fname: firstName,
            lname: lastName,
            eaddress: emailAddress
    });

    Router.go('/dashboard');
    // console log msg for debugging purposes.
    console.log("submitBtn has been clicked.");
}
});
```

```html
<template name="dashboard">
  <!--{{#if currentUser}}-->
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Videos |</li>
      <li>Games |</li>
      <li><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a> |</li>
      <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <!--<li><a>{{currentUser.profile.uname}}</a></li>-->
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!--{{/if}}-->

  <body>
    Hello {{users.fname}}!
  </body>

</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little confusing because you don't show the javascript for the template `dashboard`, which is what will determine if it's rendered.

I'm guessing you haven't subscribed to the collection that you just inserted to. [Here is how to subscribe to a collection](http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html).

Then you can return the user's name in the `dashboard` template helper.

Comment: _"you don't show the javascript for the template dashboard, which is what will determine if it's rendered.”_

Is there any way I can leave it in the registrationForm events and render it to the dashboard template? I haven’t created a js file for dashboard yet. Thanks for the assistance TIC!